# Determine what is causing the D and DL state in a process

Tags: process

I know we can't kill processes that are in the D state.

The thing is that my servers are collecting D state processes since 2015 (as you see it is running from 2015 until now).

Sometimes I can't figure out how this process reaches this state and runs like this for years. What can I do to determine the cause for some of these running 3 years old process, preferably without putting my server at risk?

I will show some examples:

```
cp since 2017
nmbd since 2016
grep since 2015 
hdparm since 2017 
gzip since 2015
```

Comment: Are all those processes trying to access the same filesystem, and if so, is that filesystem ok?

Comment: a three-year-old running kernel is doubtless at risk from lack of security updates

Comment: as Kusalananda has alluded to. Build a profile of the processes and then try to discover if any of them are related in terms of resource usage.

Comment: Look at their /proc entries for current working directory and open files, see if anything is common to all or most of them.

Comment: Right!  I used /proc/pid_number/fd and a ls -l in this directory helped a lot  to determine the causes! thank you very much for your help.